# How to return a value from a function which is passed to another function as a parameter in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function

This is my code:-

```
    function playAudio(sound,audioName)
    {
        sound = new Howl({
            src: ['/audio/'+audioName]
        });
        sound.play();
        return sound;
    }

    var sound;
    setTimeout(playAudio,5000,sound,'smooth_criminal.mp3');
```

I am passing function `playAudio` to function `setTimeout`. `playAudio()` function returns a value which I want to catch. Is there a way I can get the return value of `playAudio`.

I am looking for a solution something similar to,

```
setTimeout(sound = playAudio,5000,sound,'smooth_criminal.mp3');
```

Comment: You'd have to wrap it in another function.

Comment: @gcampbell : Can you show how it is done as I am very new to javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    var sound = playAudio(sound,'smooth_criminal.mp3');
    // do something with sound....
}, 5000);
```

This creates an anonymous function on-the-fly as you pass it to `setTimeout`. In it you can write all the code you want...

Just make sure to use the value of `sound` *only* when you have called `playAudio`, so within that anonymous function.

For example, this will not work as one might expect:

```
var sound;
setTimeout(function () {
    sound = playAudio(sound,'smooth_criminal.mp3');
}, 5000);
// not the right place to do something with sound....
// as it is not available yet.
console.log(sound);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..this is exactly what I wanted.